# Can you open QGIS projects with Q Field from Onedrive?

Tags: qfield, qgs, qfieldsync, onedrive

I configured some projects using QGIS and saved them and the respective layers on a folder in OneDrive. Then I tried to link QField to that folder and use the app to open the projects but the links seem to break.

I know there is the option to use QFieldCloud and QFieldSync but these projects are just a little too heavy for the free version to handle.

Is there a way to open them this way or do I have to resort to the premium version of QFieldCloud for it to work?